# How to select one div at one time and deselect the other divs in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html

I want to select only one div at one time and deselect the other divs at same time. But my code is not working properly. If the div is selected its color should be '#cccccc', and if the div is not selected its color should be '#ffffff'.

Here is my html code

```
$jsqla = mysql_query("select * from products where id='$product_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$jfeta = mysql_fetch_assoc($jsqla);

$formats = explode(";", $jfeta['formats']);

<div class="">
    <?php foreach($formats as $v){ ?>
        <label style="line-height: 1.25em;display: block;width: 100px;margin-right: 10px;float: left;">                         
            <div id="format-id_<?php echo $v?>" style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 9px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;border-color: #cccccc;font-family: 'SSemibold'; font-size: 13px; color: #44b7da;">                                
                <input type="radio" value="<?php echo $v; ?>" name="abc" style="visibility:hidden;" id="<?php echo $v ?>" onClick="changeColour(this)"/>
                <span style="margin:-17px auto auto 0px;display:block;"><?php echo $v; ?></span>                            
            </div>                      
        </label>
    <?php } ?>      
</div>
```

Here is my jQuery code.

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(':radio').bind('change',function(){
      var th = $(this);
      id = th.attr('id'); 
      var divid = 'format-id_'+id;

      if(th.is(':checked')){
          $('#' + divid).css('background-color', '#cccccc');
      } else {
          $('#' + divid).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      }
    });
});
```

Comment: try deselecting all the divs first then change the color of the selected div.

Comment: When you say your code is not working properly... what is happening and how does that differ from what you hope to happen?

Comment: You've `this` as a reference then why you're messing with `IDs` just set `$(this).closest('div').css(.....)`!

Comment: You'll get help a lot quicker if you make a jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  var $radios = $(':radio'), //cached reference to radios elements
    $divs = $radios.parent(); //the divs are the parent element of radio
  $radios.bind('change', function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      $div = $this.parent();

    //change the color of the current div
    $div.css('background-color', this.checked ? '#cccccc' : '#ffffff');
    //chang the color of all other divs
    $divs.not($div).css('background-color', '#ffffff');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="">
  <label style="line-height: 1.25em;display: block;width: 100px;margin-right: 10px;float: left;">
    <div id="format-id_1" style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 9px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;border-color: #cccccc;font-family: 'SSemibold'; font-size: 13px; color: #44b7da;">
      <input type="radio" value="1" name="abc" style="visibility:hidden;" id="1" onClick="changeColour(this)" />
      <span style="margin:-17px auto auto 0px;display:block;"></span> 
    </div>
  </label>
  <label style="line-height: 1.25em;display: block;width: 100px;margin-right: 10px;float: left;">
    <div id="format-id_2" style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 9px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;border-color: #cccccc;font-family: 'SSemibold'; font-size: 13px; color: #44b7da;">
      <input type="radio" value="2" name="abc" style="visibility:hidden;" id="2" onClick="changeColour(this)" />
      <span style="margin:-17px auto auto 0px;display:block;"></span> 
    </div>
  </label>
  <label style="line-height: 1.25em;display: block;width: 100px;margin-right: 10px;float: left;">
    <div id="format-id_3" style="border: 1px solid;border-radius: 9px;text-align: center;padding-top: 10px;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left: 3px;padding-right: 3px;border-color: #cccccc;font-family: 'SSemibold'; font-size: 13px; color: #44b7da;">
      <input type="radio" value="3" name="abc" style="visibility:hidden;" id="3" onClick="changeColour(this)" />
      <span style="margin:-17px auto auto 0px;display:block;"></span> 
    </div>
  </label>
</div>
```

*Note: Prefer classes to style the content instead of using inline styling*

Answer (score 2):

```
Here is the working demo
$('div').on('click',function(){
    $(this).css('color','red').siblings('').css('color','black');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/silpa/286L19jt/

Answer (score 1):

Try this : Use `.on()` instead of `.bind()`. Make use of jQuery start with selector to set background color of all `div` having id start with `format-id_` to `#ffffff`. And set selected div to `#cccccc`

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    $(':radio').on('change',function(){
      var id = $(this).attr('id'); 
      var divid = 'format-id_'+id;
      $('div[id^="format-id_"]').css('background-color', '#ffffff');
      $('#' + divid).css('background-color', '#cccccc');

    });
});
```